# MongoDB aggregation via db.runCommand(): $match by date

Tags: mongodb

I need to match documents by date in an aggregation query executed in "strict JSON" mode via db.runCommand(). These requirements are dictated by [the way JasperReports communicates with MongoDB](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jaspersoft-mongodb-query-language)

Document schema:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a6fca214420c2302a6f8985"), 
    "report_date" : ISODate("2018-01-23T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    ...
}
```

This works in MongoDB console (returns matching documents), but it doesn't work in JasperReports (throwing `com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException` in the line containing the "ISODate()" command). I'm showing only the first stage of the pipeline for clarity:

```
db.runCommand(
{
    "aggregate" : "reports",
    "pipeline" : [
        {
            "$match": {
                "report_date": {
                    "$gte": ISODate("2017-01-23")
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "cursor": {}
})
```

The same query using `$date` executes well in both MongoDB and JasperReports, but does not return any documents (0 matches in both scenarios):

```
db.runCommand(
{
    "aggregate" : "reports",
    "pipeline" : [
        {
            "$match": {
                "report_date": {
                    "$gte": {"$date": "2017-01-23T00:00:00.000Z"}
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "cursor": {}
})
```

Here goes a response example for the second query:

```
{
    "cursor" : {
        "firstBatch" : [ ],
        "id" : NumberLong(0),
        "ns" : "reports"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I observe the same behavior in range queries, like in the following snippet:

```
...
"$gte": {"$date": "2017-01-29T00:00:00.000Z"},
"$lt": {"$date": "2019-01-29T00:00:00.000Z"}
...
```

I also tried using `$dateFromString` instead of `$date`(interestingly, using this one in MongoDB 3.2 didn't result in any exceptions being thrown) - same result.

How can I run queries by date or date ranges in the "match" stage of aggregation pipeline and strict-JSON mode?

Tested versions: MongoDB 3.2.12 and 3.6.2, JasperReports Studio: 6.5.1 final

For any suggestions thanks in advance!

Comment: As noted with the duplicate, your approach is just wrong. You don't "coerce a date to a day" but instead "provide the range of dates". A single day is still a "range", beginning at the start of day and ending at the next day.

Comment: Also you need to stop thinking in terms of "difference with runCommand". There is no difference at all save you are using something with a broken API which is only calling the invocation which does not return results at a "cursor". That's it, and it makes no difference to the rest of the processing.

Comment: @NeilLunn I have edited my question. Querying with `ISODate` returns results, while querying for the same date with `$date` yields 0 results. It does NOT look like a date range issue. It looks like `$date` not being correctly used for ISO dates in aggregate queries.

Comment: It depends on what Jasper accepts. If it accept JavaScript expressions then `new Date("2017-01-29")` is generally acceptable. There's likely a question around which used Jasper for something similar before, but the same principle applies to use a "date range" rather then trying to force projection through aggregation pipelines.

Comment: FYI. My very first search result pulls up this page in the Jasper forums: https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/818338/new-date-mongodb-query Which also links to here : https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-query-mongo-isodate-data-parameter .In short the `$date` from extended JSON format is correct, so you must still have the query incorrect. See the referenced question again for the correct syntax.

Comment: I am aware of these posts on JR forums and wiki. However, these are irrelevant here as I'm executing above queries in MongoDB shell.

Comment: @NeilLunn given my comment above, I would expect you to unlock the question and remove the "duplicate" mark. This will let others chime in.